# How to add a header for each line in pandas?

Tags: pandas, header, line

I have a list of protein IDs and I want to add '>1', '>2', '>3',......'>len(list)' before each line. How can I do this in pandas?

Example:

```
protein_ID
KKP65897.1
KKP42119.1
KKP91065.1
OGY93232.1
KUK66913.1
```

I want it to be:

```
protein_ID
>1    
KKP65897.1
>2    
KKP42119.1
>3    
KKP91065.1
>4    
OGY93232.1
>5    
KUK66913.1
```

If I do this:

```
for num, line in enumerate(df.protein_ID):
    print(num, line)
```

I get:

```
0 K
1 K
2 P
3 6
4 5
5 8
6 9
7 7
8 .
9 1
10
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I want to store the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interleave` the values of `protein_ID` and `index` of `df`

```
In [619]: from cytoolz import interleave

In [620]: pd.DataFrame({'protein_ID': list(
         interleave(['>' + (df.index+1).astype(str), df.protein_ID]))})
Out[620]:
   protein_ID
0          >1
1  KKP65897.1
2          >2
3  KKP42119.1
4          >3
5  KKP91065.1
6          >4
7  OGY93232.1
8          >5
9  KUK66913.1
```

If you just need it as list

```
In [625]: ['protein_ID']+list(interleave(['>' + (df.index+1).astype(str), df.protein_ID]))
Out[625]:
['protein_ID',
 '>1',
 'KKP65897.1',
 '>2',
 'KKP42119.1',
 '>3',
 'KKP91065.1',
 '>4',
 'OGY93232.1',
 '>5',
 'KUK66913.1']
```

Details

```
In [621]: df
Out[621]:
   protein_ID
0  KKP65897.1
1  KKP42119.1
2  KKP91065.1
3  OGY93232.1
4  KUK66913.1
```